# How to Use malloc correctly in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I'm trying to allocate some memory using `malloc()` (I don't have much experience with malloc as I am just starting to learn how to use it), and I am getting a warning before compiling with my IDE.

```
int numInSeq = 0;
int i;

printf("How many numbers do you have in your sequence: ");
scanf("%d", &numInSeq);

double* sequence = (double*) malloc(numInSeq * sizeof(double));

printf("Enter the sequence of the numbers you have (seperated by spaces): ");
for (i = 0; i < numInSeq; i++) {
    scanf("%lf", &sequence[i]);
}
```

The warning is on the line where I call malloc, and it says:

`Implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)'`

Is this in incorrect way of formatting that line of code? The program still compiles, but there are some unexpected results that I get when testing.

Comment: Need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @chux I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Do not need the cast on `malloc` - i.e. `double* sequence = malloc(numInSeq * sizeof(double));` is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` as suggested by Scott, also, always make sure malloc return valid pointer by NULL check.

```
//malloc unable to allocate memory
if(sequence == NULL)
{
//return;
}
```

At the end, use free to freeup memory and to avoid memory leak.

```
free(sequence);
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to include `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

> How to use malloc correctly in C?

1. Be sure to include the correct header file.  That fixes OP's compiler warning.

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ```
2. Casting the return is allowed but frowned upon in C as being unnecessary.  Other may disagree, so best to follow your group's coding standard.

   ```
   double* sequence = /* cast not required */ malloc(...);
   ```
3. Consider the follow style as it is easier to code, review, maintain and IMO, less error prone.

   ```
   // object_pointer = malloc(sizeof *object_pointer * num_elements);
   // Example
   double* sequence = malloc(sizeof *sequence * numInSeq);
   ```
4. Remember the argument type is `size_t` and may differ in size than `int`.  `size_t` is the *unsigned integer* type of the result of the `sizeof` operator.

   ```
   void *malloc(size_t size);
   ```
5. Passing a negative `int` to `malloc()` acts like:

   ```
   malloc((size_t) some_negative_int) -->
   malloc(some_large_size_t)
   ```
6. Check the result.

   ```
   if (sequence == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
   ```
7. Eventually, free the pointer.  It is OK to free the pointer even if it has a `NULL` value.

   ```
   free(sequence);
   ```
8. If there is a chance `sequence` will get used again after free-ing, best to promptly set its value to `NULL`.

   ```
   free(sequence);
   sequence = NULL;
   ```
9. An allocation of 0 may or may not return `NULL` and is not an out-of-memory condition.

   ```
   double* sequence = malloc(sizeof *sequence * numInSeq);
   // If `numInSeq` could have a zero value, add test
   if (sequence == NULL && numInSeq != 0) {
     Handle_OutOfMemory();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Important points while using malloc :

1. Malloc function call returns you the void pointer which points to the memory location , So you should cast it to your desired data type pointer explicitly.
2. You should always remember to free the memory which you dynamically allocated using malloc. (very imp)
3. You should always check if malloc function call was successful or not.

FYI check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a `C` posted question.  Casting the `malloc()` result is a `C++` need.  Not casting the result is preferred in `C`.  The link is to a `C++` site, with good info about `C++` code, but not necessarily good info about `C` code.

Comment: Sure not a need in C (compilers point of view) but always a good programming practise...I suppose....have read this many places....is it bad practise to cast in C..? I am not sure abt this

Comment: You will find many opinions on this casting issue - some have a _very_ strong view.  At an earlier time, casting the result was preferred.  Now it is out of favor.  The thought being the it is not needed and unneeded code obfuscates.

Comment: Yes read couple of articles regarding the issue after your comment...got some good stuff to learn about...thanks..